FileSaver saveAs function does not download all the files using Promise.allSettled
I have a TypeScript function that tries to download a large number of small documents concurrently. Here's the code:
const bulkDownload = async (analyses: FullAnalysesResponse[]) => {
  setIsLoading(true);

  const promises = analyses.map(async (analysis) => {
    const documentInfo = await getDocumentInfo({ documentId: analysis.downloadFileId! });
    const attachment = await downloadDocument({ documentId: analysis.downloadFileId! });
    FileSaver.saveAs(new File([attachment], documentInfo.name, { type: documentInfo.mimeType }));
  });

  const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

  setIsLoading(false);

  results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const analysisSerialNumber = analyses[index].deviceSerialNumber;
    result.status === 'fulfilled'
      ? successfulQueries.push(analysisSerialNumber)
      : failedQueries.push(analysisSerialNumber);
  });

  return { failedQueries, successfulQueries };
};

The issue is that when I trigger this function to download multiple files at once, not all the files are downloaded. The number of downloaded files changes every time I run the function, and I never get all the files. All the API calls are working, so all the promises are successful. The issue seems to come from the FileSaver.saveAs function.
I also tried a version that uses a simple for...of loop, which works fine:
const bulkDownload = async (analyses: FullAnalysesResponse[]) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  
  const successfulQueries: string[] = [];
  const failedQueries: string[] = [];

  for (const analysis of analyses) {
    try {
      const documentInfo = await getDocumentInfo({ documentId: analysis.downloadFileId! });
      const attachment = await downloadDocument({ documentId: analysis.downloadFileId! });
      FileSaver.saveAs(new File([attachment], documentInfo.name, { type: documentInfo.mimeType }));
      successfulQueries.push(analysis.deviceSerialNumber);
    } catch (error) {
      failedQueries.push(analysis.deviceSerialNumber);
    }
  }

  setIsLoading(false);

  return { failedQueries, successfulQueries };
};

The for...of version works reliably but is slower since it downloads the files sequentially. I would like to understand why the first (concurrent) function is not working as expected. I assumed that running the downloads concurrently would be more efficient.
Any insights on why this happens, and how to fix it while keeping the performance benefits of concurrent downloads?

Perhaps the browser is overwhelmed by the number of simultaneous file save attempts? How many is a large number? Another useful bit of troubleshooting is checking what the rejection reasons are for the failed requests

The number varies but it fails for 45 files. All the request are successful the only part that is failing is when downloading to the browser.

Do the failed requests have a useful rejection reason? Are you accessing an external API, perhaps a "Too many requests" error? Oh, so ALL requests have .status === "fulfilled"? if that's the case, then yes, the number of simultaneous downloads seems to be the issue

All the promises are successful. The arrays failed request and successful request are for other part of the code not related to the issue. I've made it more clear in my question.

So you've tried "download all" in parallel and "one at a time" ... have you tried anything in between?

The map function need to return or await the promise (presumably) returned by FileSaver.saveAs

@TimMoore - a) it doesn't return anything - and b) it wouldn't help :D

Are you saying that it’s actually synchronous, or that it just doesn’t provide any way to know if it’s complete? Where does that function come from? Can you include it in the question?

@TimMoore I'm not the OP, but I am familiar with what I believe the OP is using FileSaver.js - and it does not return anything, since there's no way in code to know the status of a "download"

In that case, there’s no reason to expect the files would have finished downloading at the point the promises settle.

You verified in the network panel that all requests to the server are actually completing (check size and/or contents)?  I would consider throttling the downloads (which will indirectly throttle the saves to disk), using something like https://github.com/JMPerez/promise-throttle .  It's also more considerate to the server host (unless that's you).

@MatthewFlaschen - wouldn't promise-throttle limit the requests (which are not the problem) to be made one at a time, which the OP has done and has stated is "too slow"

@JaromandaX No, it will not limit it to one at a time.  The OP can set whatever requestsPerSecond they wish.  It can be used on any promise, but it seems FileSaver does not use promises.  By throttling network requests, it will indirectly throttle saves to disk (can't save until network request completes).

@MatthewFlaschen requestsPerSecond does not control concurrency - have you read the code?

@JaromandaX 1. Did I say I read it?  Am I also only allowed to recommend a Windows feature after I read the Windows source code?  2. requestsPerSecond does exactly what it sounds like: https://github.com/JMPerez/promise-throttle/blob/c2672ad45c67e2144d6606c6cbd9ba4b764d3a6e/lib/main.js#L72 .  If you're trying to draw a distinction between 10 "concurrent" requests fired in immediate succession, then waiting vs. 10 requests fired 0.1 seconds apart (with requestsPerSecond 10), that's not a meaningful distinction in this context.

@MatthewFlaschen - requests made using promise-throttle will run at a concurrency of 1 at a time - which is what the OP does in the last block of code. The OP states this is too slow, so, regardless of the value of requestsPerSecond, using promise-throttle will be at most as performant as the OP's one-at-a-time code, in fact, it will be significantly slower, since every request will incur a setTimeout penalty

The OP's final for...of version is strictly one in flight at a time, since it awaits download completion before continuing the loop.  promise-throttle starts one at a time (then waits a time interval (not for promise resolution) before starting another), but there is no limit on the number in flight simultaneously (if you think there is such logic, link to it).  If you set requestsPerSecond to a high enough value, there will be more than one in flight at once.

I'm hesitant to answer this, because I fear there may be an element of "magic number" about it
What you want is to control the number of concurrent file downloads (i.e. not the API requests, since they seem to work fine as fast as you can request them), but this is not exactly possible, since FileSaver.js can't tell you when a file has completed downloading. However, maybe with some tweaking of the "magic numbers" you can get a consistent (faster than one at a time) result.
So, the following code contains the allSettledConcurrent function that combines your .map and Promise.allSettled into one function
In case you're wondering, I wrote this function, along with a suite of others (allConcurrent, throttleAllConcurrent, throttleAllSettledConcurrent, throttlePromise etc) years ago for various use cases
// MAGIC numbers
const afterDownloadDelay = 100;
const concurrency = 10;

async function allSettledConcurrent(items, concurrency, fn) {
    const results = new Array(items.length);
    const queue = items.map((item, index) => ({ item, index }));
    const doFn = async ({ item, index }) => {
        try {
            const value = await fn(item);
            results[index] = { value, status: "fulfilled" };
        } catch (reason) {
            results[index] = { reason, status: "rejected" };
        }
        return queue.length && doFn(queue.shift());
    };
    const slots = queue.splice(0, concurrency).map(doFn);
    await Promise.all(slots);
    return results;
}

const bulkDownload = async (analyses: FullAnalysesResponse[]) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    const results = await allSettledConcurrent(analyses, concurrency, async (analysis) => {
        const documentInfo = await getDocumentInfo({ documentId: analysis.downloadFileId! });
        const attachment = await downloadDocument({ documentId: analysis.downloadFileId! });
        FileSaver.saveAs(new File([attachment], documentInfo.name, { type: documentInfo.mimeType }));
        if (afterDownloadDelay) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, afterDownloadDelay));
        }
    });

    setIsLoading(false);

    results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const analysisSerialNumber = analyses[index].deviceSerialNumber;
        result.status === 'fulfilled'
            ? successfulQueries.push(analysisSerialNumber)
            : failedQueries.push(analysisSerialNumber);
    });

    return { failedQueries, successfulQueries };
};

